# Exporting mysql query result to .txt file

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.7

I want to export query result into .txt file

The path of .txt file and query is dynamic

```
 DELIMITER //
 create procedure test(filepath text , _query text)
 BEGIN
 SET @sql = CONCAT(_query, ' into OUTFILE ' ,filepath ); 
  prepare s from @sql;
   EXECUTE s;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
  END // 
  DELIMITER ;
```

When call procedure test it shows me:

```
CALL  test1('C:/Users/Tajamul Hussain/Desktop/file database/test.txt ','select firstname from t1 where id =1');

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'C:/Users/Tajamul Hussain/Desktop/file database/test.txt' at line 1
```

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag as your question has nothing to do with Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embrace the `filepath` in quotes. This works for me (tested on MariaDB 10.4, but should work on older versions as well):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test(filepath text, _query text)
BEGIN
  DECLARE stmt TEXT;
  SET stmt := CONCAT(_query, ' into OUTFILE \'' , filepath, '\''); 
  PREPARE s FROM stmt;
  EXECUTE s;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

By the way, it's not good practice to use user-defined variables inside stored programs, like `@sql` in your procedure, because they retain their values between calls. (I think it will be OK in your procedure, though, unless you use `@sql` elsewhere.) `DECLARE` your variables instead.